# Access to Realm database file

Tags: xamarin.android, realm

Does it possible to have access to the same Realm database file from different applications? If it possible how I can manage it? I use Xamarin version.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Realm to connect to specific database file which stored at shared folder for your applications.

Read more about this in [Configuring a Realm](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#configuring-a-realm) paragraph. Also you may be interested of default realm configuration - read [this](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#the-default-realm).